# Input type checkbox issues: checkbox.value and setState working incorrectly on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have the below simplified code with a checkbox that is intended to change state onClick, but I am not able to get the right value when clicked. It is in a React project with no jQuery.

The state element confirmCheck is initialized false, then the handler, handleConfirmClick is called onClick of the checkbox, and setState is called to turn confirmCheck to true. On the first click, the setState does not turn true, but on subsequent clicks, it toggles. This seems to be common problem fixed using jQuery.

The input value is set to this.state.confirmCheck somewhat in line with React docs
(https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), and the value in the appears element toggles correctly, but when I console.log checkBox.value, the value is false(!?) when it is true inside the element.

Based on my reading, the problem seems to be something to do with the DOM rendering the input, but I cannot find a clean solution. If all else fails, I could use a variable to test and pass click, but I would like to use state if possible.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Edit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      confirmChecked: false
    };
 }

handleConfirmCheck(event) {
  const checkBox = document.getElementById('editConfirmCheck');

  this.setState({ confirmChecked: !this.state.confirmChecked });
  console.log(this.state.confirmChecked);
  //logs false on first click

  console.log(checkBox);
  // on first click, logs <input type="checkbox" id="editConfirmCheck" value="true">

  console.log(checkBox.value);
  // logs false!!?? on first click

}

renderEditForm() {
      return (
        <div>
            <label className="confirm-radio">
              <input type="checkbox" id="editConfirmCheck" value={this.state.confirmChecked} onChange={this.handleConfirmCheck.bind(this)} />  Check to confirm changes then submit
            </label>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.renderEditForm()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because setState is asynchronous. Before it will update and change the DOM, your console log has already been called.

Comment: Oh, thanks for shedding light on that. I console logged on a callback on setState and it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code the only mistake you did was typo  in `render method` it should be `this.RenderEditForm()` instead of `this.renderEditForm()` and everything seems to be working fine

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was simplifying my code. I don't have that mistake in my real code. Perhaps there is something in the real code that is throwing things off, but I don't want to put all my code up since it's really long. Thanks for looking at it any ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.
You have closed the class body in the  `RenderEditForm()` method.
Also you are trying to call a method that has never defined.
 `<div>{this.renderEditForm()}</div>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/2vjmp10xky

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I was simplifying my code. I don't have that mistake in my real code. Perhaps there is something in the real code that is throwing things off, but I don't want to put all my code up since it's really long. Thanks for looking at it any ways.